# What is supposed to be searchable in the 'Resources' tab input on the Event Attendees standard field?

Tags: event

[image]I can see that by default you are able to add Users, Contacts to an event etc. But what is the Resources tab/input for? My sandbox has no data so unsure of what object this references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resources tab is for booking shared resources like conferences rooms for events. This creates an EventRelation record in the background that references a Calendar.

To set up a Calendar for this you can following the steps in this help article: [Create and Manage a Public Calendar or Resource Calendar](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_groupcal.htm&type=5)